# Send email, if files (in git) were changed

Tags: git, email

I need to send a notification (email, slack) if files are changed in git.

Does anybody know how to do this correctly?

One solution, which I see is using PHP.

```
exec("git status")
```

And if result is different from `nothing to commit` send a notification.
The PHP file would be run through cron (every hour).

Comment: If you use something as GitHub you could use the API and do the request via cronjob there.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You need to decide of you want this for your local repo or your remote. If local, and if you polled with above, you might miss something (polling once an hour seems slow, but not sure what the rate of your updates are). Better to use a git hook, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks. If on remote, you would need to look at the server side hooks.

Comment: I mean on remote server.

Comment: ok, are you using GitHub? They have info on their web hooks here https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/. If you control the server, you can write the hooks yourself on that server to send an email.

Comment: Its all laid out here for BitBucket https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html

Comment: You did not understand, I don't need webhooks, I need track any changes on my server, and if file was changed, I want to send notification. And I want to use git for this issue